# Subvarieties in cotangent bundles of Riemann surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $\pi \colon T^*X\rightarrow X$ be its holomorphic cotangent bundle. Other than (1) cotangent fibers and (2) ramified coverings in $T^*X$ of $X$ minus some divisor, what are examples of irreducible analytic subvarieties of $T^*X$? Give me examples.

Comment: If $Y \subset T^*X$ is irreducible, then the projection $\pi : Y \to X$ is a point or the curve itself, giving (1) or (2). It seems to me you listed all the possible examples.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks for the comment, but I don't understand your argument. You may assume Y is proper? If not, the statement is wrong, since the image of Y can be an open subset of X. Maybe you can give me some more clues.

Comment: I assumed that $Y$ is closed. If not, you can first take the closure of $Y$, apply the argument, and then remove whatever closed subvariety you want.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks again, but I don't understand yet. For example, suppose X is a complex line, then $T^*X$ can be seen as $\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $(x, y)$ be the standard coordinate of $\mathbb{C}^2$.  Consider $Y=\{y=1/x\}$. Then the projection of Y is $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$, is open. What do you mean in this case?

Comment: Did you solve the problem in the special case that $X=\mathbb A^1$? I don't know how to exploit the assumption of irreducibility. Unlike the algebraic analogue, seemingly we cannot simply localize with respect to $X$.

Comment: @D.Namrebod To complete the analysis given in Nicolas Hemelsoet's comments, take the closure of $Y$ in the projective completion $\bar T=\mathbb{P}(T^*X\oplus O_X)$. Then $\bar Y$ is either a fibre or  "horizontal" possibly meeting the divisor at infinity $\bar T-T^*X$.

Comment: @DonuArapura Thanks for the comment. How can I see that the horizontal part is  a ramified covering?